# iOS - Interface Builder - Adding elements as subviews to a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, subviews

In interface builder I have a viewController and It's main view (view A). I have added another UIView (view B) onto the main view and now I would like to add more elements to view B but I want Xcode to recognize them as subviews of view B rather than subviews of view A.

When you drag elements onto a view in interface builder they initially are added to the main view.
You can then drag and move them to be under another view in the interface builder navigator but they still don't seem to become subviews of that view.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can try moving your views using the list on the left. Just drop your subview on its parent view.

Comment: I did that but they still don't actually become subviews. As in the are not in the [viewB subviews] array.

Answer (score 2):

Add inside/under view B in xib.It will make the elements added to view B the subviews of view B only,not view A

This way it will look

[image]